# Movie from tiff pictures

Tags: conversion

How can I create a movie from multiple tiff files in ubuntu?

I have multiple tiff picture files and I want to merge them into a movie. Each picture should show for about 0.1s. The final movie format is not relevant and no fancy transitions are reauired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with ffmpeg from the CLI. There is some information on [this page](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) which I have pasted in below

First, rename your pictures to follow a numerical sequence. For example, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg,... Then you may run:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
```

Notice that ‘%d’ is replaced by the image number.

```
‘img%03d.jpg’ means the sequence ‘img001.jpg’, ‘img002.jpg’, etc...
```

If you have large number of pictures to rename, you can use the following command to ease the burden. The command, using the bourne shell syntax, symbolically links all files in the current directory that match *jpg to the ‘/tmp’ directory in the sequence of ‘img001.jpg’, ‘img002.jpg’ and so on.

```
x=1; for i in *jpg; do counter=$(printf %03d $x); ln -s "$i" /tmp/img"$counter".jpg; x=$(($x+1)); done
```

If you want to sequence them by oldest modified first, substitute $(ls -r -t *jpg) in place of *jpg.

Then run:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i /tmp/img%03d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
```

The same logic is used for any image format that ffmpeg reads.