# Create movies from images and sound files scripting transitions using the console?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, video, image-processing

I need a program without GUI that accepts some kind of scripting language capable of transitions (fade, scale...) and generates movie files like avi, mkv... from images like jpg, png and audio like mp3...

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the transitions but the rest should be easily do-able with `ffmpeg`. See [Movie from tiff pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77567/movie-from-tiff-pictures/77575#77575)

Comment: For transititons see [ffmpeg -Video Filters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Filters)